# how can I check the page speed of my wordpress site which is locally hosted on WAMP server?

Tags: wordpress, wamp, pagespeed

The site load time is frustratingly slow and I want to fix it with information I've found here so I'm trying to know if that is gonna have any effects.

Comment: do you use Chrome? in the dev window, click on "Audits" ond run a performance test

Comment: Thank you. Worked.